# dataTables column titles breat and the sorting handle go to the next row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a JQ DataTable that has a problem with the column title.

Something like:

```
    <table id="someTableId">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title dfas 1</th>
            <th>t itle fasd 2</th>
            <th>title asdf  3</th>
            <th>title sdf 4</th>
            <th>title asdf 5</th>
            <th>title asdf 6</th>
            <th>title  dfad7</th>
            <th>title adf 8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla lo</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla blong body</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla lonody</td>
            <td>bla long body</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla lo</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla blong body</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla lonody</td>
            <td>bla long body</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla lo</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla blong body</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla lonody</td>
            <td>bla long body</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla lo</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla blong body</td>
            <td>bla bla long body</td>
            <td>bla bla lonody</td>
            <td>bla long body</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The title keep breaking and either complete words goes to the next line or just the sorting handle.

You can see an example at : http://jsfiddle.net/qGVsb/

even with high `"sScrollX": "150%",` the sorting handles go one line down.

Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: inspect the css of sort icons in browser console....can tweak to make their positions absolute. try `whitespace:nowrap` also for `<th>`

Comment: Thanks tried did not work

Comment: of course it will work, given the proper css selectors and rules. It is css that positions them now